# How to learn multi-labeled hierarchical data?

Tags: machine-learning, hierarchical-clustering

I have an existing data set that represents the products from an e-commerce website that can be categorized by the following (simplified) tree structure:

[image]

The root node represents all the products on the website, the intermediate nodes represent the product categories and the leaf nodes represent the actual products. For each product, I typically have its photos, specifications, and descriptions.

Some properties about the hierarchical structure:

1) The hierarchy allows me to put multiple labels to a given product. For example, Jacket-2 will be labeled as "Women's" and "Coats & Jackets"

2) A given product can appear in multiple leaf nodes. For example, I might have another node called "Latest", and the latest products in that season (jackets, pants, accessories, etc) will also show up in that node.

3) The subtrees won't necessarily have the same depths.

4) In reality, there will be hundreds or thousands of items.

My question is, **is it possible to apply machine learning on the existing data to train a classifier and to learn how the products are labeled, so that when new products come out I can automatically tag them?**